# Overlap of children in ExpandableListView involuntarily causes checkboxes to check in separate groups

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview, overlap

I am using a Navigation Drawer with an ExpandableListView contained inside. The ExpandableListView has groups with children that have checkboxes next to each child. When certain checks are checked, the checks within a collapsed group below the expanded group are checked as well.

Can someone explain *why* this is happening, and what potential fix(es) there is for my situation?

I'll provide images and my code to better explain this issue.

Here are my groups.
[image: Here are my groups.]

And here is 'Assignments' expanded (without anything chosen).
[image: Assignments (no checks)]

And here is 'Archived' expanded (without anything chosen).
[image: Archived (no checks)]

So, now that I check 'Subject 4' under 'Assignments'...
[image: Subject 4 checked]

Involuntarily, 'Overdue' inside of collapsed 'Archived' was chosen as well.
[image: Overdue involuntarily checked]

Likewise, when I voluntarily check 'Completed' under 'Archived'...
[image: Completed voluntarily checked]

'Subject 3' is chosen involuntarily inside collapsed 'Assignments' as well.
[image: Subject 3 involuntarily checked]

And here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_commentary_behind_nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="Swipe from left, and eventually this \nframe will hold fragments that change depending on which checkboxes are selected" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my source:

```
 public class MainNavigationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnChildClickListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ExpandableListView drawerList;
private CheckBox checkBox;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout_test);

    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    initDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer_layout_test, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initDrawer() {
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout2);
    drawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer2);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new NewAdapter(this, groupItem, childItem));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        drawerList.setIndicatorBounds(310, 350);
    } else {
        drawerList.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(310, 350);
    }


    drawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id){
            Fragment fragment;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            Bundle args;
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    fragment = new AssignmentManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(AssignmentManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    fragment = new SubjectManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(SubjectManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(drawerList);
                    break;

                // for now, just SubjectManager, but soon they will lead to Settings then H/Feedback
                case 3:
                    fragment = new SubjectManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(SubjectManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    fragment = new SubjectManagerFragment();
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(SubjectManagerFragment.ARG_PARAM1, "" + groupPosition);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame2, fragment).commit();
                    if (drawerList.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        drawerList.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    } else {
                        drawerList.expandGroup(groupPosition, false);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked On grooop: " + v.getTag() + "|" + groupPosition,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });

    drawerList.setOnChildClickListener(this);


    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("open");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

         // Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("close");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setGroupData() {
    groupItem.add("Assignments");
    groupItem.add("Archived");
    groupItem.add("Subjects");
    groupItem.add("Settings");
    groupItem.add("Help / Feedback");

}

ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChildGroupData() {
    /**
     * Add Data For Assignments
     */
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<SubjectInfo> sial = new ArrayList<SubjectInfo>();
    List<SubjectInfo> sil = SubjectInfo.listAll(SubjectInfo.class);
    sial.addAll(sil);
    for (int go = 0; go < sial.size(); go++) {
        child.add(sial.get(go).subjectName);
    }
    childItem.add(child);

    /**
     * Add Data For Archived
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Archived");
    child.add("Completed");
    child.add("Overdue");
    childItem.add(child);

    /**
     * Add empty children for Subjects, Settings, and H/Feedback
     */
    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    childItem.add(child);
    childItem.add(child);
    childItem.add(child);
}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked On Child: " + v.getTag() + childPosition + "|" + groupPosition,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.show_child_subject_checkBox);
    checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    //Update SugarRecord value for SubjectInfo
    SubjectInfo si = SubjectInfo.findById(SubjectInfo.class, (long) (childPosition+1));
    si.subjectChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
    si.save();
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my adapter:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
public LayoutInflater minflater;
public Activity activity;
private final Context context;

public NewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
    this.context = context;
    groupItem = grList;
    this.Childtem = childItem;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
    TextView text = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_submenu_item,parent,false);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submenu_textView);
    text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));

    convertView.setTag(tempChild.get(childPosition));
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:
            //Expands with the size of the cereal array
            return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
        case 1:
            //Expands with the size of the Archived Cereal Array
            return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
        default:
            //List does not expand
            return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItem.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_group_item,parent,false);

    }

    ((TextView) convertView).setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition));
    convertView.setTag(groupItem.get(groupPosition));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true; //was false, and was why toast wasn't presenting. Now that True, it does.
}

}
```

And my SubjectInfo code (including boolean checked):

```
public class SubjectInfo extends SugarRecord<SubjectInfo> {

public String subjectName;
public int subjectGrade;
public boolean subjectArchived;
public boolean subjectChecked;

// still deciding on whether subjects can be archived or not... if they can then all assignments
// should be archived with them (and can be restored the same way an assignment can.)
// otherwise, deleting a subject would mean (deleting/archiving all assignments) > (user option)

public SubjectInfo () {}

public SubjectInfo (String name, int grade, boolean isArchived, boolean isChecked) {
    subjectName = name;
    subjectGrade = grade;
    subjectArchived = isArchived;
    subjectChecked = isChecked;
}

}
```

And here are my layouts for drawer_group_item and drawer_submenu_item, respectively:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:background="@color/white"
android:text="hello, fix?"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
/>
```

submenu...

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/submenu_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/show_child_subject_checkBox"
    android:checked="false"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Comment: the answer below is right, in that the problem almost certainly lies in your adapter code.

Comment: now that the adapter code is posted, where do you think in the code is causing the check overlapping issue? Why would selecting something in a completely different group cause the child underneath (which isn't even displayed because the group is collapsed) to be chosen as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Now that I can see your code, right off I notice three major problems:

- You don't set the initial state of the checkbox in `getChildView()`.  Now to set that checkbox properly you need access to the `SubjectInfo` where the checkbox value is stored.  However, your adapter doesn't even have access to the `SubjectInfo` object!  You stripped the name off and sent that to the adapter.  You could create another `ArrayList` of booleans for the checkboxes, but why duplicate?  You already have the data in `SubjectInfo`, just get those objects into the adapter so you can use their data to create the child views.
- Your `onChildClick()` doesn't take into account which group the child was in.  So if the user clicked on a child under "Archived", which doesn't even have `SubjectInfo`, you are taking the child index and finding its `SubjectInfo`.  In other words, your `onChildClick()` is treating every child as if it was a Subject child.  You need to check the value of `groupPosition` to make sure the user clicked on a Subject child.
- In your `setChildGroupData()`, you have this code:

  ```
  child = new ArrayList<String>();
  childItem.add(child);
  childItem.add(child);
  childItem.add(child);
  ```

  That means that each group is accessing *the same list*.  So when you go to put an child item in the Subjects group, that same child item is also going to show up in the Settings group.

The best advice I can give you is to try to start thinking of the `ExpandableListView` more like an abstract hierarchical list data structure and less like a visual/touchable element.  A `TextView` maps to a `String`.  A `CheckBox` maps to a `boolean`.  `RadioButtons` map to an `enum` that you define.  Then make sure that the methods to get the views use this data, and that there are callback methods from the views that update the data.  The adapter interface is meant to interact with data like this, so if you can nail that data structure, you will solve a lot of problems.

---

You didn't provide the code for your `NewAdapter` class, but I bet I know what's happening: You are probably displaying a recycled view with garbage view data.

The view recycling mechanism of the adapter classes means that when you get a recycled view, you have to initialize *everything* in the view because you don't know what state it was in before it was recycled.

The corollary to this is that the adapter has to provide a *current and up-to-date* model so that the adapter view can display the correct data *at any given time*.  What this means to you is:

- your adapter data model (i.e. `SubjectInfo`) has to have a boolean flag to track the state of the checkbox.  This boolean flag will be used in `getView()` to set the initial checkbox display as checked or unchecked.  You didn't post your `SubjectInfo` class either, but your code isn't referring to any boolean in that class, so I assume you don't have that.
- your checkbox needs to have an `OnCheckedChangedListener` that will update the corresponding boolean flag in the adapter's data model and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the adapter view know that it needs to be refreshed.

If you're already doing that, then post your `NewAdapter` and `SubjectInfo` code and we can try to figure out what else may be going wrong.

P.S. The code line

```
checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
```

can be replaced with

```
checkBox.toggle();
```

Comment: Please review the question now after I edited it. I actually did have a way to record the checks through SugarRecord dataBasing, but I haven't moved on from there yet in terms of implementing those booleans. 
The "leaking through" of the checkBoxes complicated implementing the booleans because I figured if the view recycled and constructed the list from the booleans, it would just construct the with the leaking-through still happening. 
Do you think it's possible that drawer_group_layout and drawer_submenu_layout are just textviews (not necessarily filling up the item box) and allow the leak?

Comment: Okay, but why does the overlapping even happen? I still haven't gotten that solved and it's a fundamental reason for why I'm not continuing with implementing the booleans with functions in the code. 
The ones with the same list are empty, so I intended for them to have the same empty list. Archived at the moment doesn't have a function, so the checkboxes aren't going to be assigned an implementation until the overlapping is solved.

Comment: The overlapping happens because you don't set an initial state of the checkbox in getChildView(), so you are at the mercy of ExpandableListView's view recycling.  If you are skeptical, try an experiment:  In getChildView(), get the checkbox and just set it to unchecked.  Now when you check a checkbox and then go back to it, it will most likely be unchecked.  However, your other child views that you didn't touch will remain unchecked, so at least the overlapping part is fixed.

Comment: I am working on code right now to do exactly that. I'll get back to you tomorrow when I get a chance to integrate what I've planned from your lead

Comment: So far, so good, thanks. But, upon collapsing the header, the children (checkboxes) reset. Closing the app before collapsing the items does save the checks, however. Why would the checks reset upon collapsing the group?

Comment: The same phenomenon occurs as the comment above when I scroll below the checkboxes I've toggled so those checkboxes are off the screen. When I scroll back to see them, they have reverted to their original checked/unchecked state.

Comment: The issue is solved by notifyDataSetChanged(); but that doesn't have the adapter recreate all the arraylist data from the dataBase and thus the recyclerview, which only recreates from the arraylist each time, so the arraylist must be updated separately.